# Implementing VQ attack on image with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

I am trying to make a project in which I manipulate image with several tampering attacks. Since I am new to this, I referred to some research papers and found that to attack an image, one just gets an object from an image and pastes it on another. For example you can see this image:
[image]

I want to implement the same (adding or cutting out specific object from the image) in my project. But I am not able to figure it out about how to implement this with Spyder and OpenCV. I tried to search but it gave me concepts of frameworks and deep learning which is out of my league as for now. Is there any simpler way to achieve this ?

Comment: if you need a cutting edge result, you have to go for cnn...

Comment: @StanlyMoses can you please elaborate about that concept?